# Wheel grinding on brake piston

Tags: brakes, wheels, grinding

I recently replaced the brake pads on my 2014 Nissan Altima. Once done I took it for a drive to make sure everything sounded and felt correct and I heard this awful grinding noise. I check the pads and had resolved it was my rotor that needed to be machined when my wife noticed scratches on the inside of the wheel. Upon inspection I noticed that when I replaced the wheel it rubbed on the edge of the brake calliper/piston or whatever it is that holds the brake pads to the rotor. I tried to remove the brake pads thinking I had the wrong size but even with no pads it still rubbed. What could be the cause?

Comment: Caliper is what you're looking for, and if it's touching the wheel and it didn't before, something has gone back together wrong.  Do you have aftermarket wheels?

Comment: I thought the same thing but I cannot see a problem with how I am attaching everything back together. Videos online look the same as what I do and I changed the rear brakes a year ago and had no issues. They are aftermarket wheels

Comment: Are the wheels staggered (different sizes front vs rear)? I had this happen once when I mistakenly put the narrower wheel on the back instead of the front, and the offset wasn't sufficient to completely clear the caliper. I had a similar experience when I mistakenly put a caliper bolt in that was too long, and it rubbed the rotor.

Comment: The caliper position does change when new pads are put in.  I guess it could be a wheel clearance issue, but that should go away if you put the old pads in and re-compress the brakes.

Comment: Put the old brake pads on and recompressed them and I still have a grinding noise, checked for clearance and it's no longer touching the wheel. I can't tell the difference between inner and outer pads, should I be able to?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the vacuum plate behind the rotor